# Remove value from popup lov once its selected

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm trying to create lov in which once the machine is started it should not show in popup lov after submit.

Popup lov sql is as below:
select machineid,machinenm from machinemaster where idlemachine = 'Y';

but the issue is once machine is status change and this query not finding result for the perticular machineid so in lov it shows blank.

Please suggest any workaroud.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, query you posted looks wrong. Generally speaking, list of values' query returns two values in the following order:

- display value
- return value

We usually display *names* and return *IDs*, which means that you'd probably want to use

```
select machinenm as display_value,
       machineid as return_value
from machinemaster 
where idlemachine = 'Y';
```

---

> the issue is once machine is status change ...

How is that statement reflected in query you posted? There's no "status" column nor "change" status itself; where clause says `where idlemachine = 'Y'` - no status, no "change".

---

> ... and this query not finding result for the perticular machineid so in lov it shows blank

I believe that you should set the **Display extra values** property `ON`. Help says:

> An item may have a session state value which does not occur in the given list of values definition. Select whether this list of values displays this extra session state value. If you choose to not display this extra session state value and there is no matching value in the list of values definition, the first value in the list of values is the selected and displayed value.

If you're seeing the `NULL` value, it means that you actually set

- display extra values to `OFF`
- display null value to `ON`

Comment: Display Extra values is ON.
in this case idlemachine is the "Status" column which shows machine is idle or not.
Issue is when I select the machine which have idle status Y(yes) then it turns into N(NO) Because machine will be in use.

So when next time page refresh LOV will not have Machines which are in use.

and that's why its not showing data which machines are in working mode.